# Create a shortcode in a plugin showing the content

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode in an existing Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin. Where do I put the code to create the shortcode?

The plugin displays a table with all the available variations on any given variable product on the product page.
The table reacts to what the customer selects on the attributes form.
I want to make a shortcode so that I can show this in a tab on the product page instead of before the add to cart button as is now. Where should I put the code for the shortcode?

```
<?php
    /*
        Plugin Name: Variations On Product Page
        Description: Display all the available variations on the product page
        Version: 1.2
    */


    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_VER', '1.2' );
    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

    require_once 'settings.php';

    if ( ! isset( Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['enabled'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'variations-on-product', VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_URL . 'assets/variations-on-product.js', [ 'jquery' ], VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_VER );
        wp_localize_script( 'variations-on-product', 'variations_on_product_settings', apply_filters( 'variations_on_product_js_settings', [
            'options' => Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings(),
        ] ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'variations-on-product', VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_URL . 'assets/variations-on-product.css', [], VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_VER );
    } );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', function () {
        global $product;
        /* @var WC_Product $product */
        if( !$product->is_type('variable') ) return;
        ?>
        <style>
            #product-variations .attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail {
                max-width: 100px;
            }

            table#product-variations .custom_form .quantity {
                float: none !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                margin-right: 0 !important;
            }

            table#product-variations .custom_form .input-text.qty {
                width: 100% !important;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            table#product-variations .custom_form button.button.alt {
                width: 100%;
            }

            table#product-variations .custom_form p.stock {
                margin-bottom: 3px !important;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px
            }
        </style>

        <table id="product-variations">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php if( !Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['hide_thumbnail'] ): ?>
                    <td>Image</td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>*</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="#" class="button" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;" id="product-variations-load-more"><?=Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['load_more_text'] ?: 'Load more'?></a>

        <?php
    } );

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', function ( $default, $product, $variation ) {

        /* @var WC_Product_Variation $variation */
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <tr>

            <?php if( !Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['hide_thumbnail'] ): ?>
                <td>
                    <?= $variation->get_image() ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td>
                <?= $variation->get_name() ?>
                <p>
                    <small><?= $variation->get_sku() ?></small>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $variation->get_price_html() ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if ( $variation->is_in_stock() ) : ?>
                    <form class="custom_form" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <?php
                            if( !Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['hide_stock_status'] ) {
                                if ( $variation->managing_stock() ) {
                                    echo wc_get_stock_html( $variation );
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            if( !Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['hide_qty'] ) {
                                woocommerce_quantity_input( [
                                    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $variation->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $variation ),
                                    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $variation->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $variation ),
                                    'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : $variation->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
                                ] );
                            }
                        ?>

                        <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation->get_id() ); ?>" class=" button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $variation->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

                    </form>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $default['c_template'] = apply_filters('vop_variation_template', ob_get_clean(), $variation);

        return $default;
    }, 10, 3 );

    // Hide add to cart on product

    if ( isset( Variations_Product_Settings::getSettings()['hide_product_addtocart'] ) ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', function () {
            ?>
            <style>
                .single_variation_wrap {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            </style>
            <?php
        } );
    }
```

I tried to add the following code but did not work.

```
<?php
    /*
        Plugin Name: Variations On Product Page
        Description: Display all the available variations on the product page
        Version: 1.2
    */

add_shortcode( 'minkod', 'mitt_lilla_shortcode_handler' );

    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_VER', '1.2' );
    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    define( 'VARIATIONS_ON_PRODUCT_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
```

I added the function:

```
function mitt_lilla_shortcode_handler () {    

    $myshortcode ='
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', function () {
        global $product;
        /* @var WC_Product $product */
        if( !$product->is_type('variable') ) return;
        ?>
```

And in the end:

```
> <style>
>               .single_variation_wrap {
>                   display: none !important;
>               }           </style>            <?php       } );    ';} return $myshortcode; }
```

Comment: Hello Tobias and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a bit more context as to what you want to accomplish, what you have tried and a more reduced sample code? That's a lot of code to go through for somebody attempting to answer your question.

Comment: @dovetalk I want to make a shortcode letting me show the content this plugin generates where ever I want on the product page, for example in a tab.

Comment: @dovetalk Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I just came across your question and noticed that it had a lot of complex code. Questions tend to get faster answers when you show you've done some work yourself and provide the simplest possible code that exhibits the problem.